# How do you calculate exponents in HIVE

Tags: hive

Simple question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere so somebody else will probably experience the same frustration.

In Hive, how do I calculate field1**field2.

Comment: I am not so experienced in Hive. are you trying to multiply the two fields, if so did please look into this wiki link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ArithmeticOperators

Comment: [Field 1] to the [field 2] power.  So if field 1 is 5 and field 2 is 3 then I want 5 cubed.

Comment: pow(double a, double p), power(double a, double p) source:http://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-functions#mathematical-functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

[image: power]

Source: [Hive Mathematical Functions](http://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-functions#mathematical-functions)